# How to use hash_map in shared memory

Tags: c++, windows, stl, shared-memory

I want to do inter process communication using shared  memory. In the shared memory  I want to use hash_map. Is it possible to create hash_map in shared memory?

Comment: There is no standard C++ component called `hash_map`, so I guess you are using some particular library - you would need to consult the documentation for that library to see if it supports creating the map nodes in a particular area of memory.

Comment: Are you using the *original* [Standard Template Library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library)? It's mostly obsolete these days, and basically all its functionality (and more) have been incorporated into the standard library. For example `has_map` is [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map).

Comment: And if you use `std::unordered_map` then you need to provide a custom allocator that "allocates" memory from the shared memory, otherwise it will allocate from the heap and the data wont be shared. In general, dealing with dynamic structures of any kind is not trivial when used together with all kinds of IPC, especially shared memory.

Comment: If `boost` is an option, you might want to look into [boost::interprocess](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/interprocess/quick_guide.html#interprocess.quick_guide.qg_interprocess_map)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `boost::interprocess` library. It supports interprocess communication through sharing and supports advanced concepts such as shared memory containers.